# Word that means good deed, offering, contribution

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to find a word -- preferrably a short one -- that means:

- Good deed
- Help
- Offering
- Contribution

This word will be used as the name of a feature in a software app where a user helps another in a meaningful way. Not just answer a simple question but render a service such as design a logo for another user or help write a business plan or design a website. So, there's real time and effort spent by the user to help another and there will be no monetary gain for him/her.

Any suggestions for a word that we can use within this context? I've been using dictionary and thesaurus apps and these are the best ones I've come up with so far but I feel there's something better.

To clarify further, this will be the name of a feature. Think of it like “Search” or “Sent Items”. So, it could be the “Contributions” feature. Hope this clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Provide a sentence that it would fit into.

Answer (score 1):

Boon

boon /buːn  /
▸ noun

1 [usually in singular] a thing that is helpful or beneficial:
the route will be a boon to many travellers.

2 archaic a favour or request.

– ORIGIN Middle English (originally in the sense ‘request for a favour’): from Old Norse bón.

Comment: So far this is my favorite one. Is “boons” the plural version?

Comment: Yes, I believe boons works as the plural. I especially liked this because of the archaic meaning. Good for a brand type of thing because the word has deep roots in the language

Comment: And it’s short and easy to spell/pronounce!

Answer (score 1):

Benevolence
Benevolence has two definitions that it goes by. The most noted is a human quality, the disposition to be kind. The other definition it goes by is "an act of kindness." If you were going to use benevolence, you would most likely refer to the second definition. I don't know if the word being defined two ways makes a difference to you or not.

Charity
the giving of money, food, or help to those who need it, or an organization that does this:
or
A generosity and helpfulness especially to those in need or suffering.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Magnanimous, Magnanimity, are: *the fact or condition of being magnanimous; generosity.*
"both sides will have to show magnanimity"*
**synonyms:**
*generosity · charitableness · charity · benevolence · beneficence · open-handedness · big-heartedness · great-heartedness · liberality · humanity · nobility · [more]*  "... the virtue of being great of mind and heart."